# Passing arguments to an IIFE

Tags: javascript

What's the correct syntax for passing arguments to an IIFE stored in a variable?

Example below tells me that `foo` is not defined, regardless on if I call the function or not:

```
var bar = (function(foo){

    return { 
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        } 
    }

})(foo);

console.log(bar.getFoo(1));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eSTkL/

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The IIFE is *immediately* invoked. You are passing `foo` to it at the moment of invocation, and I suppose it's undefined.

What gets stored in `bar` is not the IIFE, but the object returned by the IIFE, that doesn't have anything to do with foo (beside having access to it via closure). If you want foo to be `1`, don't pass that value to `getFoo`, but to the IIFE itself:

```
var bar = (function(foo){

    return { 
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        } 
    }

})(1);

console.log(bar.getFoo()); // 1
```

If you want a getter and a setter (actually, getter/setter-like functions), use this:

```
var bar = (function(foo){

    return { 
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        },
        setFoo: function(val) {
            foo = val;
        }
    }

})(1);

console.log(bar.getFoo()); // 1
bar.setFoo(2);
console.log(bar.getFoo()); // 2
```

Comment: So it's not possible to do something like `bar(1)` to make `foo === 1`?

Comment: You can create a setter-like method the same way you created a getter. Inside that method, you can set the value of foo to whatever you pass. Are you trying to accomplish something practical, or just trying to understand how it works?

Comment: To answer your question; it's a little bit of both. I'm trying to simulate a "class" where I only expose a certain part of it. But you gave me enough info to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The `foo` that you're passing to the IIFE isn't defined. You should define `foo` in the outer variable environment first.

```
var foo = "foobar";

var bar = (function(foo){

    return { 
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        } 
    }

})(foo);
```

---

Or just define it directly in the argument position.

```
var bar = (function(foo){

    return { 
        getFoo: function(){
            return foo;
        } 
    }

})("foobar");
```

---

Also note that you're passing a value to `getFoo()`, but you're not actually using it in the method.

```
//         v----never gets used
bar.getFoo(1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply:

```
var bar = (function(){

  return { 
    getFoo: function(foo){
        return foo;
    } 
  }

})();

console.log(bar.getFoo(1));
```

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Soupedenuit, this should be the accepted answer indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const bar = (foo => ({ getFoo: _ => foo }))("foobar");

console.log(bar.getFoo())
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is the `foo` that you are passing into the function.