# JavaScript : What does the " x(x)(v) " syntax mean?

Tags: javascript

While doing some reading on the [necessity of type checking](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/you-might-not-need-typescript-or-static-types-aa7cb670a77b) and enjoying Eric Elliot's approach to functional programming, I decided to revisit arrow functions. With this in mind I found a great 2015 article on MDN Hacks by Jason Orendorff '[ES6 In Depth: Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)'. Towards the end of the article I come across the lambda-calculus example, transpiled to ES6 with arrow functions as follows:

Here is an example of the sort of “program” a mathematician could write, using Church’s λ notation:

```
fix = λf.(λx.f(λv.x(x)(v)))(λx.f(λv.x(x)(v)))
```

The equivalent JavaScript function looks like this:

```
var fix = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))
               (x => f(v => x(x)(v)));
```

I should also add that I've tried the Babel transpiler on the code and it still returns pretty much the same kind of syntax as in x(x)(v):

```
var fix = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)));
```

is transpiled to

```
"use strict";

var fix = function fix(f) {
  return function (x) {
    return f(function (v) {
      return x(x)(v);
    });
  };
};
```

The part that puzzles me is the `function (v) { return x(x)(v) }` part and `x(x)(v)` in particular? What does this syntax mean?

There has got to be something simple that eludes me, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. Your  advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's just two function calls right after each other

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! do you happen to know where is this documented?

Comment: `..do you happen to know where is this documented? ` - Function execution syntax should be covered in any basic JavaScript for Beginners guide, document, book, or MDN webpage like Feifanz linked.

Comment: This type of behavior has been in javascript since a long time ago, just not in this form.  Have a look at how [Babel transpiles this code to "normal javascript" equivalent](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=var%20fix%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20(x%20%3D%3E%20f(v%20%3D%3E%20x(x)(v)))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(x%20%3D%3E%20f(v%20%3D%3E%20x(x)(v)))%3B)

Comment: @James Thanks for the tip! I should have mentioned I did use babel's transpiler in the hope to figure out what was going on. to my surprise the "return x(x)(v)" remained.

Comment: @Fran you would think, but it's not the case. I think I recall seeing it somewhere and it's more of a mathematical notation, something along the lines of "f of x of y"

Comment: @ArmsWideOpen I don't think too much about it or over-complicate it. In JavaScript I see `()` after anything I usually assume it's executing a function and that what ever precedes `()` is itself or returns a function. For all I know that might not always be true for all cases but it's a good start I would hope :)

Comment: would anyone care to provide an example of this code working with arithmetic functions? i would really love to see an example illustrated with simple inputs and an output var fix = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x(x)(v)` is two chained function calls. `x(x)` returns a function, which is then called with `v` as an argument. This is equivalent to:

```
const y = x(x);  // y is a function
y(v);
```

Concrete example:

```
const x = function(foo) { return function(bar) { console.log(bar); } };
const y = x(x);
y(v);
```

Comment: do you happen to know where has this been documented?

Comment: Not this syntax in particular; it's just a "clever" use of normal function call syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions

Comment: sorry to bother you, but would you care to provide an example of this code working provided for by simple arithmetic functions? var fix = f => (x => f(v => x(x)(v)))

Comment: That's not possible, because none of the existing simple arithmetic functions return a function. However, perhaps this guide will help explain functions that return a function: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions

Answer (score 0):

Upon conducting more research into the subject of what exactly is this syntax and how it properly works, I have found that x(x)(v) is a mere IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). I believe Babel would not transpile it because it is a legacy notation. As James mentioned in the comments to the original question "This type of behavior has been in javascript since a long time ago".

If you want more information, you'll just have to word your search right, knowing the above. While [MDN's page on IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is scarce to say the least, the 'quick example' mentioned there should steer you in the right direction. A similar question, therefore was answered on stackoverflow before with "[Passing Arguments to IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552553/passing-arguments-to-an-iife)", as well as on quora with "[What are the end-parameters of an immediately-invoked function expression for?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-end-parameters-of-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression-for)".

The part that will throw most people off with this particular question of 'what is x(x)(v) syntax?' is the absence of parenthesis around x(x), like so:

```
x(x)(v) == (x(x))(v)
```

Now this is completely different and most people now will know straight away, that (v) is just an argument to the x(x) IIFE.

For the simplest of examples, just try out this piece of code:

```
function x (val) {return (val)};

var v = "v_variable";

console.log(x(x)(v));
```

or this snippet:

```js
function x (val) {return (val)};

function fix (v) {
  var v = "I am the result variable, successfully returned by the x(x)(v) IIFE";
  return x(x)(v)
//  return (x(x))(v)
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fix();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Ivoking x(x)(v) IIFE returns the same result as the generally accepted and widely known (x(x))(v) IIFE notation</h3>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```